# RegEx: Only one instance of underscore

Tags: javascript, java, regex, regex-group

I'm looking for a regex pattern that will accept the following:

`[foo_bar]` or `{foo_bar}`

**Where:**

either `[` `]` or `{` `}` acts as wrappers

`foo` and `bar` can be *anything* except `_` repeated between 1 to n times

`_` should only appear once and should be between `foo` and `bar`

**Sample matches:**

`[1Ab_23c]`

`{abcDefGhjk_Z}`

`{1_abcDefGhjk}`

**Sample mismatches:**

`{1Ab_23c]`

`{_1Abde_fg4567_2_}`

`{1Abde_fg4567_2}`

`1Ab_23c`

This is what I have right now but I'm still missing the *only one* `_` part.

```
^{.+_.+}|\[.+_.+]$
```

I'm guessing that a `(?!_).+` should somehow be there but I can't piece them together.

Comment: Try [`/^(?:\[(?=.*]$)|{(?=.*}$))[^_]+_[^_]+[\]}]$/`](https://regex101.com/r/E0ZxFX/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [complemented character set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-negated-character-set) - `[^_]` (all but underscore):

```js
const pattern = /\[[^_]+_[^_]+\]|\{[^_]+_[^_]+\}/;

// matches
console.log(pattern.test('[1Ab_23c]'));
console.log(pattern.test('{1Abdefg4567_2}'));
console.log(pattern.test('{1Ab_23c}'));

// mismatches
console.log(pattern.test('{1Ab_23c]'));
console.log(pattern.test('{_1Abde_fg4567_2_}'));
console.log(pattern.test('{1Abde_fg4567_2}'));
console.log(pattern.test('1Ab_23c'));
```